# How do I create a .properties file from JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, properties

I want to make a `.properties` file to use instead of numerous cookies. I have been trying to figure out how to do this by googleing, but maybe I'm just missing something or not looking for the right thing.

This will eventually be user based, so I wanted to know if I could get it to create a new file based on the user's login, but every beginners guide I find seems to say just make a text file by hand.

Could someone provide me with a page that explains how to do this well, or give me the basic code that I'll need to get me started.

And also what code I need to add new key,value's to the file and how to get the values from it.

Comment: It's not much different from in normal Java code. Just start with the properties tutorial as available at oracle.com. But have you considered a database? Also note that writing Java code in JSPs is discouraged in general and that you should use servlets for this.

Comment: My boss wants me to use a properties file. Would this need like a seperate class and I just use JSP to edit it, or what? This is all a learning experence for me.

Comment: It's after all just the same Java code. But doing so in JSP will only end up in maintenance trouble.

Comment: So how do I create a .properties file without opening notepad and typing one out and saving it as a .properties?

Comment: Just check chapter "Saving Properties" in the properties tutorial. Or use the usual `File` API, it does then not matter whether it's a properties file or not. By the way, you might want to reframe the question like that. Right now your question is way too broad. One question at a step, please.

Comment: Well i'm trying to figure this out, i really didn't have a clue how to ask it. 
How do you specify where the file gets saved?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Properties.list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#list%28java.io.PrintStream%29). Using this method you can easily write properties into an OutputStream and with help of ByteArrayOutputStream you can convert theese properties into a string.

To read properties from a file use [Properties.load](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29).

Unfortunately there's no standard Java API to just add or remove a property from a file - you'll have first to load the whole file into a Properties instance and then save it back into the file after you made the required changes using [Properties.setProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

[java.util.Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) has load and store methods that will read and write the properties for you.  In that case you just add to the Properties map and then store it to an OutputStream or a Writer.

For doing it user based, you would need a directory to store it in and then base the file name on the user name or id, but make sure it is safe for a file name.